# Sort the item from two lists in one list while keeping the sequence in the original lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two unsorted lists as followed:

```
A = [1, 3, 1.75]
B = [0, 1.5, 2, 4]
```

I want to make a list that includes the numbers in A and B in a sorted manner (e.g. ascending). However, I want to keep the sequence from each list as well. The suitable output would look like something below:

```
AB = [0, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 1.75, 4]
```

Do you have any ideas/hints on how to do this? The original problem includes 150 lists that need to be merged into one list like above. Thank you for your ideas beforehand!

Comment: How do you define the 150 lists? I assume you don't do  A=..., B=..., etc. 150 times?

Comment: @mcsoini: They are in a dataframe (df) that is multi-indexed with three levels. Each list can be extracted through df.groupby(level=[0,1]) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a "merge" problem to me:

```
def merge(lists):
    iters = [iter(s) for s in lists]
    heads = [next(s) for s in iters]
    res = []
    inf = float('inf')

    while True:
        v, n = min((v, n) for n, v in enumerate(heads))
        if v == inf:
            return res

        res.append(v)
        try:
            heads[n] = next(iters[n])
        except StopIteration:
            heads[n] = inf


lists = [
    [1,2,3,8],
    [1,7,4],
    [6,9,1,2,3],
]

print(merge(lists))
## [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
```